# What type of tree / bush is this, which blooms white flowers in Massachusetts?

Tags: identification, trees

I'm trying to figure out what tree this is. This is in Massachusetts (USA), hardiness zone 6a [-10 to -5(F)]. It blooms white flowers.

[image: tree]
[image: leaves]
[image: closer leaves]
[image: closer leaves 2]

Comment: Second photo is out of focus so its not possible to see the leaves clearly, and impossible to tell whether the round things are seed cases from previous flowers earlier this year, or are flower buds. An in focus picture would be good... and where are these trees in the world?

Comment: I will try to get a better picture. This is in Massachusetts (USA), hardiness zone 6a [-10 to -5(F)]. It blooms white flowers.

Comment: I voted to close because details (like leaf venation) are not clear and the rest of the characteristics are common between many species. I wish the OP would return to add a better pic.

Comment: J Dilly, are you able to get us more information? What do the white flowers look like? White time of year do they bloom? I'm going to vote to close this question while we wait, but remember you have time to edit and reopen, so we can try to help you.

Comment: I just uploaded 2 more pictures.

Comment: Yeah, it's a Euonymus.Check out the terminal leaves in your second-to-last photo and this photo: https://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/shrub/winged-burning-bush and this one: https://landscapeplants.oregonstate.edu/sites/plantid7/files/plantimage/eualc24.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess Cornus kousa, Japanese Dogwood.  The flowers aren't true flowers they are modified leaves akin to Poinsetta flowers.  I am seeing the horizontal branching which is portrayed beautifully as 'layers' in a dogwood.  The leaves look similar. Have you noticed little red 'fruit' looking things?
[image: Korean Dogwood later in the season]

The other idea was Japanese Snow Bell.  Styrax japonica.  I feel badly that I am unable to see whether you've got opposite leaves, odd pinate...those buds remind me of this tree. [Japanese Snowbell Styrax japonicus](https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7339/10784979836_6879377dbf_b.jpg)

Comment: I just uploaded 2 more pictures.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Euonymus. In the original photos, I didn't see the "wings" for E. alatus (burning bush), but the multi-stem form matches, as do the green buds. If the pictured shrub is 8 ft x 8 ft, then it could be the compactus cultivar (which would explain the missing wings): http://www.vivaipriola.it/wp-content/themes/x_lapriola/piante/cartimgs/EU05105_big.jpg

The added photos show more detail and confirm, to my mind, that it's E. alatus or relative like the Wahoo tree (as it's known here) - Euonymus europeaus (http://media.gettyimages.com/photos/euonymus-europaeus-picture-id697386211?s=170667a)

This species has highly showy fruits in the autumn, with colorful leaves (but not as colorful as burning bush); there are more than a few cultivars. Wahoo trees are most often tree-form rather than shrub form.

Comment: the red "sten" between leaflets has me leaning toward a euonymus